# What is the way to grow vocabulary?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the best way to increase your vocabulary? I feel that vocabulary books, tests, or quizlets take too long. I know reading is definitely a good option, but is there any other ways to increase vocabulary? Thanks!

Comment: I Recommend to wacth a lot of movies and series

Comment: *Listening* (and particularly, ***speaking***) is definitely a *better* option - no physically normal native speaker initially learns their *own* language by reading.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't learn English by reading, but I did grow my vocabulary far beyond my peers as a child by being an avid reader. I had a couple embarrassing moments mispronouncing words I had read but not heard spoken (omnipotent), but at least I knew the words existed. The problem with listening is that most folks use a fraction of their vocabulary when they speak unless they're giving a pretty formal speech.

Comment: Subscribe to [A Word a Day](https://wordsmith.org/awad/).

Comment: @ColleenV: True. I haven't seen a copy for donkey's years, but when I was a kid we always had old issues of *Readers Digest* around the house (particularly, in the *loo!* :) - they always had a little item called *Increase your [Word Power](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Readers-Digest-Word-Power-Quiz/dp/0895779013)*, as I recall. I don't know that I ever *learned* the words though - probably just looked at them, thought they were interesting, and promptly forgot them since I had no actual *use* for them as a ten-year-old.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your mention of Readers Digest just sent me down an Internet rabbit hole that has ended up with me ordering a set of [monkey selfie prints](http://www.djsphotography.co.uk/). I have fond memories of that publication. My parents would challenge me to use a new word in a conversation each day, and Word Power was far easier than riffling the dictionary and picking something at random :)

Comment: @ColleenV: That's an intriguing one you've come out with right there! My first thought when I saw your [*riffling the dictionary*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22riffling+the+dictionary%22) was "keyboard bounce on the **f**", but there's a written instance (though in my defense there are 4 instances of [*rifling the dictionary*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22rifling+the+dictionary%22)). After due consideration, I prefer yours. Not that I was unfamiliar with ***riffling** playing cards*, but you've introduced me to a nice new turn of phrase, ty! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It never occurred to me that [riffling](https://youtu.be/T7OKmdvyfD0?t=50s) a book could be confused with rifling through something. Maybe I learned it because I had a job in a library when I was in grade school - I don't think it was one of my Word Power words, lol.

Comment: For increasing vocabulary, it depends on what you want to do. Is this for general vocabulary or for increasing fluency with basic vocab? Then general fluency measures (lots of reading/writing/listening, making notes of unknown words and repeating sentences with them) will help. but after a certain point, word lists are going to be it because the words will be so rare. Schaumburg outlines are great because they give vocab in categories (auto, kitchen, politics, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you live in a country where the language you want to learn is spoken, strike up conversations with as many people as you can. Write down the lyrics of songs and practice singing them with the music video, to develop speed and get a sense of the rhythm of the language. Listen carefully to expressions other people use, in conversations, on social media and TV, and in movies. Ask a patient person to correct your mistakes. Read material that interests you, to familiarize yourself with specialized vocabulary.I used to read jokes in Greek. Write as much as you can, for example, in conversations on Facebook. That's how I learned Greek.

Comment: You need to be very confident to start talking to strangers, especially if you know only the basics of the language and don't pronounce words very well. Otherwise, it is the ultimate way of learning the language.

Comment: I used to go to a souvlaki place and talk to the two women there. I lived by myself for six months so wherever I went, I needed to speak Greek - at the supermarket, etc. I always had an English-Greek dictionary on me, and I was extremely lucky to be learning the easiest language in the world to learn to read - it takes ten minutes to go through the alphabet, and you can start reading. Obviously I spoke in broken Greek, like any tourist - they're used to tourists in Greece, and in those days, 1978, not many Greeks spoke English, so it was sink or swim.